# intellij idea ideavim substitute with new line

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

In vim, I can substitute a word into two lines like the following

```
:%s/word/wo^Mrd/g
```

`^M` is inserted with `Ctrl-V Enter`.
But how Can I do this win IntellijJ IDEA, ideavim?
ideavim ignores `Ctrl-V` in command-line mode.

IntellijIdea 2021.1.1, ideavim.

Answer (score 5):

1. It's *command-line mode*, not "command mode", which is synonymous with "normal mode".
2. IdeaVim being a far from perfect Vim emulator, there is no reason whatsoever to expect it to work like Vim.
3. The correct way to do what you want in Vim is to use `\r`:

   ```
   :%s/word/wo\rrd/g
   ```

   which, incidentally, works fine in IdeaVim.